# Close tkinter window after the script execution is complete

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, process

I am working an a tool where-in I am getting the initial user credentials and an unique identifier via `Tkinter` GUI interface. Post that after a lot of data fetching and processing I would get a report into an excel sheet using `xlsxwriter` package.

I generally exit/close the tkinter window using `destroy()` method on click of a button. Here, I want to show the user the status of the report creation in a Tkinter `messagebox` and then close the main window.

Note: I am using `.pyw` extension, so that the end user who is using the tool shouldn't see the console. So once the user hits the submit button, I will show a label at the footer of the window saying `"Processing ..."`

Sample code:

```
from tkinter import *
#Some other libraries are imported

mScrn = Tk()
mScrn.title("Report Generation Tool v1.0")
mScrn.geometry("200x180")
mScrn.resizable(False, False)

tk_uid_lbl = Label(mScrn, text="MVS1 Username")
tk_uid_lbl.pack()
tk_uid_lbl.place(x=20,y=20)

uid = StringVar()
tk_uid = Entry(mScrn, bd=3, textvariable=uid)
tk_uid.pack()
tk_uid.place(x=150, y=20)

tk_pwd_lbl = Label(mScrn, text="MVS1 Password")
tk_pwd_lbl.pack()
tk_pwd_lbl.place(x=20,y=60)

pwd = StringVar()
tk_pwd = Entry(mScrn, bd=3, show='*', textvariable=pwd)
tk_pwd.pack()
tk_pwd.place(x=150, y=60)

tk_ver_lbl = Label(mScrn, text="Version #")
tk_ver_lbl.pack()
tk_ver_lbl.place(x=20,y=100)

ver = StringVar()
tk_ver=Entry(mScrn, bd=3, textvariable=ver)
tk_ver.pack()
tk_ver.place(x=150, y=100)

tk_sub_button = Button(text='Submit', command = show_footer)
tk_sub_button.pack()
tk_sub_button.place(x=150, y=150)

mScrn.mainloop()

#The data provided in the GUI is used for access and a lot of process goes on

#Close the Tkinter window post the process is done
```

Thanks in Advance. I am using Python3

Comment: I would request a reason before downvote

Comment: What is the question? How is the code you've provided related or [mcve]?

Comment: @sushant047 After the script execution is complete there is nothing left to do. You seem yo know how to close a window and how to add a label so what is your actual question? Placing widgets after having packed them does not make sense to me but that seems unrelated to your question.

Comment: I don't know how to get the data before closing the mainloop(). In that aspect once that is closed I cannot show the label on the GUI and then close with user consent (i.e. after clicking 'ok' in message box)

Answer (score 0):

I am having a hard time understanding your question. My understanding is that using `destroy()` is exactly what you are looking for. Use `destroy()` when you are finished. You basically already answered your own question.
 I would find it helpful if you could explain your question more thoroughly. I agree with Goyo but I cannot comment.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to get the data before closing the mainloop(). In
>   that aspect once that is closed I cannot show the label on the GUI and
>   then close with user consent (i.e. after clicking 'ok' in message box)

I don't undestand where is your problem, you can save your data with a lot ways, list, module, object, file, etc.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
import threading
import time

# Simulate a process
def get_data(callback):
    while True:
        if len(data) == 10:
            break
        time.sleep(.5)
        data.append(random.randint(1, 200))
    callback()


def wait_end(label, tk_var_end, num=0):
    label["text"] = "Processing " + " ." * num
    num += 1
    if num == 4:
        num = 0
    if not tk_var_end.get():
        mScrn.after(500, wait_end, label, tk_var_end, num)


def execute():
    for entry in (tk_uid, tk_pwd, tk_ver):
        entry['state'] = tk.DISABLED
    tk_sub_button.destroy()
    tk_process_lbl = tk.Label(mScrn)
    tk_process_lbl.pack()
    tk_process_lbl.place(x=150,y=150)

    tk_var_end = tk.BooleanVar(False)
    wait_end(tk_process_lbl, tk_var_end)
    process = threading.Thread(
        target=get_data,
        kwargs=(dict(callback=lambda: tk_var_end.set(True)))
    )
    process.start()

    mScrn.wait_variable(tk_var_end)
    mScrn.after(500, tk_process_lbl.config, dict(text='Process completed'))
    mScrn.after(1500, mScrn.quit)


mScrn = tk.Tk()

data = []

mScrn.title("Report Generation Tool v1.0")
mScrn.geometry("400x180")
mScrn.resizable(False, False)

tk_uid_lbl = tk.Label(mScrn, text="MVS1 Username")
tk_uid_lbl.pack()
tk_uid_lbl.place(x=20,y=20)

uid = tk.StringVar()
tk_uid = tk.Entry(mScrn, bd=3, textvariable=uid)
tk_uid.pack()
tk_uid.place(x=150, y=20)

tk_pwd_lbl = tk.Label(mScrn, text="MVS1 Password")
tk_pwd_lbl.pack()
tk_pwd_lbl.place(x=20,y=60)

pwd = tk.StringVar()
tk_pwd = tk.Entry(mScrn, bd=3, show='*', textvariable=pwd)
tk_pwd.pack()
tk_pwd.place(x=150, y=60)

tk_ver_lbl = tk.Label(mScrn, text="Version #")
tk_ver_lbl.pack()
tk_ver_lbl.place(x=20,y=100)

ver = tk.StringVar()
tk_ver= tk.Entry(mScrn, bd=3, textvariable=ver)
tk_ver.pack()
tk_ver.place(x=150, y=100)

tk_sub_button = tk.Button(text='Submit', command = execute)
tk_sub_button.pack()
tk_sub_button.place(x=150, y=150)

mScrn.mainloop()

print(data)
```

But, you can also make your own class which will inherit of Tk, in this class you could override the quit or destroy method of Tk.